# Get The Facebook Friends List in Android Activity Other then where User Logged In

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Login in my Android Application. i am able to login successfully and display user name in a TextView but i am facing the below problem

After successful facebook login when i close the application and opens it again, i am getting logout button but the profile Name is missing. i want the activity should again call the facebook API to get the user name.

i am using the code below
in my OnCreate Event

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.connectWithFbButton);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "user_friends");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, nCallback);



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> nCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                if ( profile!= null)
                {
                    String FirstName = "";
                    String LastName  = "";
                    String ProfilePic = "";
                    String PId = "";
                        FirstName = URLEncoder.encode(profile.getFirstName(), "utf-8");
                        LastName = URLEncoder.encode(profile.getLastName(), "utf-8");
message.setText( "Hello  " + profile.getFirstName());
                }
   }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you are looking for something like this

```
    Profile profile;
    String name;

    try{
        profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        name = profile.getName();
    }catch(NullPointerException npe){
        npe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`onSuccess` is only called when you log in so you need to `getCorrentProfile` **outside** `onSucess` note that if you are not logged in this will return null

so in onCreate check if `getCorrentProfile` is null, if so let the user log in you will get the result in onSuccess, if not you use the profile to get the name and other info